# object is not saved in array

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone

I have the following code that parses json into custom objects, parsing works fine i have a problem with saving the objects.

```
-(void)handleCities:(NSNotification *)notification
{
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self name:@"_getInitialData" object:nil];

if(![notification object])
{
    NSLog(@"Something went wrong");

    return;
}

// Convert data to a dictionary
NSMutableDictionary * data = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:(NSMutableData *) [notification object] options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers error:nil];

// Loop over all the data
if([data objectForKey:@"data"] != (id)kCFBooleanFalse)
{
    for(int i = 0; i < [[[data objectForKey:@"data"] objectForKey:@"cities"] count]; i++)
    {
        CityObject * object = [[CityObject alloc] init];

        // Loop over all the properties
        for(NSString * key in [[[data objectForKey:@"data"] objectForKey:@"cities" ] objectAtIndex:i])
        {
            NSString * _key = key;

            if([object._remap objectForKey:key])
            {
                NSString * value = [object._remap objectForKey:_key];

                NSLog(@"Notice [%@] Remapping \"%@\" to \"%@\"", self.class, _key, value);

                _key = value;
            }

            // Save the value for easy access
            NSString * value = [[[[data objectForKey:@"data"] objectForKey:@"cities" ] objectAtIndex:i] objectForKey:_key];

            // Does the value have a value
            if((id)value == [NSNull null])
            {
                value = @"";
            }

            // Set the value for key
            [object setValue:value forKey:_key];
        }

        NSMutableDictionary * set = [[[data objectForKey:@"data"] objectForKey:@"cities"] objectAtIndex:i];

        int count = (int)[[set objectForKey:@"categories"] count];

        for(int b = 0; b < count; b++)
        {
            CategoryObject * category = [[CategoryObject alloc] init];

            for(NSString * key in [[set objectForKey:@"categories"] objectAtIndex:b])
            {
                NSString * value = [[[set objectForKey:@"categories"] objectAtIndex:b] objectForKey:key];

                if((id)value == [NSNull null])
                {
                    value = @"";
                }

                [category setValue:value forKey:key];
            }

            NSLog(@"Category %@",category.class);
            NSLog(@"Object : %@",object.class);
            NSLog(@"Object Categories : %@",object.categories.class);

            // i can print the category object fine here

            [object.categories addObject:(CategoryObject *)category];
        }

        [self.cities addObject:object];
    }
}

CityObject * city = [self.cities objectAtIndex:0];
CategoryObject * category = [city.categories objectAtIndex:0];
NSLog(@"Category Name : %@", category.name);

[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self name:@"_getInitialData" object:nil];
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"getInitialData" object:nil];
}
```

**CityObject.h**

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import "Object.h"

@interface CityObject : Object

@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString * name;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString * id;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString * state;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString * image;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString * term_order;

@property (nonatomic, strong) NSMutableArray * categories;

@property (nonatomic, strong) NSMutableDictionary * _remap;


@end
```

**CityObject.m**

```
#import "CityObject.h"

@implementation CityObject

-(id)init
{
if(self = [super init])
{
    self._remap = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
    self.categories = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

    [self._remap setObject:@"state" forKey:@"new_city"];
}

return self;
}

@end
```

**CategoryObject.h**

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import "Object.h"

@interface CategoryObject : Object

@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString * name;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString * icon;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString * id;

@end
```

Before i add the CategoryObject to my array i can retrieve the values without a problem it is when i NSLog at the end i cannot get the values / objects out of the array's.

What am i doing wrong since it works great when i add the CityObjects but not when i "parse" the categories. I **can** read them fine before i add them to the object.categories

**Error / Output**

```
-[__NSDictionaryM name]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7a482760
2015-03-24 09:21:05.649 10things[16968:337325] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSDictionaryM name]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7a482760'
```

Comment: This fragment in the error message: `-[__NSDictionaryM name]` Indicates to me that you *think* you are using a `CityObject` (or `CategoryObject`) when in fact you are using an `NSDictionary`.  This happens all the time with JSON; people simply don't understand the types of objects they are manipulating.

Comment: `NSLog(@"Category %@",category.class);`
`NSLog(@"Object : %@",object.class);`
`NSLog(@"Object Categories : %@",object.categories.class);`
                
Give the right classes back, it goes wrong the moment i add them to the  array

Comment: The `unrecognized selector` never lies...

Comment: That may be true, but i don't see anywhere in the code where i possible converted the object to a dictionary

Comment: You don't see it because your code is too complicated.  I just started looking at it and got depressed pretty quickly.

Comment: Like aren't you getting bored writing "[[data objectForKey:@"data"] objectForKey:@"cities"]" again and again and again? It doesn't only make it hard to read, it makes it impossible for the compiler to use type checking, and it makes your code big and slow.

Comment: A property starting with an underscore? Why on earth? And a property named id? Seriously? id is the type for "pointer to NSObject" and should never, ever be used for anything else. You are setting yourself up for trouble.

Comment: If you have a better way to handle those dictionaries, please enlighten me because i have no better way in solving those pesky things. Im fairly new so if you have a better method let me know

Comment: @gnasher729 i have taken your feedback into consideration an have changed the wrong variables names and such thanks. but still have no clue into how i can avoid the dictionary mess

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved, i did not have a strong pointer to the model, the Dictionary was magically being replaced to a `NSMutableDictionary` Once i had a strong handle everything worked properly. (thanks for the code feedback)